# Android: MediaPlayer, How to get properties of an audio stream?

Tags: android, properties, stream, media-player

I can successfully listen to an audio stream with the MediaPlayer interface, but how can I get properties of the stream like the current bit rate, or the stream text (lots of streams like on line radios include the currently playing track)?

I tried to find this information but couldn't, if these things are possibly is there a list somewhere on the android dev site where the various available 'properties' are listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the Android DEV site is the site with all class information - but sometimes hard to find what you need. In that case, checking the java source of the class can be quite helpful.

From a quick look into the SDK, there is an `onInfoListener` interface, which you can implement in a class extending `MediaPlayer`. That needs you to have `public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)` implemented. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html states there is a what=`MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE`.

But - checking google for that would give the idea that this never gets called :-/
So eventually you are on your own with that...

Comment: As I understand it, the InfoListener is only notified when the streaming lags. The "what' returned is only an integer, there isn't much place for artist, title, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I could be making this harder than it needs to be, but you can decode a frame of the Stream with [Jlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) or some other MP3 decoding library to get the info you are looking for.  Not sure if there is a way to do this with just the Android sdk.

Answer (score -2):

If your stream is a shoutcast/icecast stream then you can use the utility class at http://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/ to extract the metadata including the song title. 
Alternatively, you can build your own metadata extractor. Take a look at http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html for more info.

Comment: This project is uselesss, considering shoutcast offers a light web service at `http://yp.shoutcast.com/Metadata_Info1.php?surl=<stream_url>`. Definitelly overkill and creates many dependencies