# mediaplayer stream id3 push

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to creat my own Radio app on Android and I struggled when I tried to get meta data from live mp3 stream, so the question is:
`How to get Android MediaPlayer OnInfoListener notified when live stream meta data is changed and display it?`

I found other topics here, that said I could use this `MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE`, but it never gets updated. Here is the topic: [Android: MediaPlayer, How to get properties of an audio stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842842/android-mediaplayer-how-to-get-properties-of-an-audio-stream)

Maybe some of you have solved this?